# Brew cannot link postfix due to /usr/local/lib/libdns.a from bind in macos

Tags: homebrew, bind, macos-sierra, postfix-mta

I am working on a formula to brew install postfix from source code in the my mac mini. I am able to make the makefiles, make, and make install the software, however brew link can not be completed due to the libdns.a needed to be linked into /usr/local/lib. There is a link in the directory with the same name from bind already installed previously. So, I need to ask for help to resolve the conflict.

1. Is there any workaround to relocate the link to /usr/local/lib/postfix, /usr/lib, or somewhere else?
2. Can I ignore the very link and just complete the rest?  What will fail?